# Rails/Actionmailer error trying to edit email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm using rails 4 and actionmailer to allow users to edit a generated email before letting it send.

When I try to load the editing page, I get this error.

```
Showing /var/www/rqm3/app/views/rfis/mail.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's line 5 for referrence.

```
 <%= text_area_tag :email_body, @mail_message.html_part.body.raw_source,class:"tinymce", rows:40, cols:120 %>
```

I have @mail_message set from my controller here.

```
  def mail
    @mail_message = RfiMailer.send_rfi(current_user, @rfi)
  end
```

Thanks to anyone that helps.

EDIT:

rfis_controller:

```
class RfisController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rfi, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :mail]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /rfis
  # GET /rfis.json
  def index
    @rfis = Rfi.all
  end

  # GET /rfis/1
  # GET /rfis/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /rfis/new
  def new
    @rfi = Rfi.new
  end

  # GET /rfis/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def send_rfi

  end

  def mail
    @mail_message = RfiMailer.send_rfi(current_user)
    # @mail_message = RfqMailer.placeholder_message(current_user, Rfq.last)
  end

  # POST /rfis
  # POST /rfis.json
  def create
    @rfi = Rfi.new(rfi_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfi.save
        format.html { redirect_to mail_rfi_url(@rfi), notice: 'Rfi was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rfi }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rfi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /rfis/1
  # PATCH/PUT /rfis/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfi.update(rfi_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @rfi, notice: 'Rfi was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @rfi }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @rfi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /rfis/1
  # DELETE /rfis/1.json
  def destroy
    @rfi.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to rfis_url, notice: 'Rfi was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_rfi
      @rfi = Rfi.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def rfi_params
      params.require(:rfi).permit(:due, :rfi_type, :parties, :reference, :svg_ref, :vendor_ref, :email_body)
    end
end
```

rfi_mailer.rb

```
class RfiMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from:"test@test.com"
    def send_rfi(user)
        mail(to:"someemail", subject:"test")
    end
end
```

Comment: okay first of all:  you are missing to use the user-edited-template in your mailer .

Comment: right now I'm just trying to get the email to show in the "mail" view's TinyMCE .  In the past I've done something like this:
      @mail_message.html_part.body.raw_source.replace params[:email_body]

Comment: so after you create some "RFI" you want to go to the "mail" method - where you display the textarea. correct?

Comment: That's correct.  It looks like the problem is with the mailer that doesn't seem to set any of the variables when I call RfiMailer.send_rfi(current_user)

Comment: please go into your console and mail_message = RfiMailer.send_rfi(User.find(xyz)) and look if he is having 2 parts.

Comment: looks like it only creates one part... thank you for your patience, this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: so do you have 2 templates? one for the text and one for the html part?

Comment: I only have an html version, I didn't think it would matter because i only have one for the other mailer doing the same thing essentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, some cleanup

```
before_action :set_rfi, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :mail]
```

you can also write

```
before_action :set_rfi, except: [:index, :new]
```

**back to topic**

html_part is nil, thats why you cant use the body of it and it throws a exception.
please make sure that your email is having 2 templates, one for the text-part and one for the html-part. further details on that at the rails Doc

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views

Comment: Thanks a ton, I didn't realize this would make a difference.

Comment: actually i dont know how exactly i could help, but if its working out now, im happy. let me know if you need further assistence